# graphware handshake Exception

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

Hello trying simple example for graphware .throwing me below error.

**Handshake Exception. Unable to negotiate a version to use. Proposed versions were [1,0,0,0]**

sample code is given below. point to notable is the server is not ssl enabled to requests are http

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
 ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.xx.xx.xx:7687')
 ->build();

$query = "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 1";

try {


   $result = $client->run($query);

   foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
     print_r($record);
     exit();
   }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
```

}

Comment: this is some thing how to enable http request support by default

Answer (score 0):

GraphAware Neo4j driver can only be used with old version of Neo4j. During [Handshake](https://boltprotocol.org/v1/#handshake), the client first sends a magic four byte preamble (6060 B017) followed by four protocol versions it supports, in order of preference. The GraphAware Neo4j PHP driver sent the only one version it understands : 1.0.

The 4.0 and 4.1 servers are no more compliant with bolt protocol 1.0. So handshake failed because servers and client can find a compatible version. It's very difficult for PHP and Python developers to build a driver for Neo4j 4.0, Neo4j 4.1 [because Neo4j team do not publish any documentation of new versions of bolt](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12361). This task seems to havea low priority. I'm surprised, because I don't understand how their teams can develop their driver in java, javascript without this documentation. *(I'm currently developing a solution for Neo4j 4.0 and neo4j 4.1, but it take times without doc, because I have to analyze TCP Stream with wireshark)*

So, at this time, you have two solutions: Try the [Open Native Graph Database](https://github.com/graphfoundation/ongdb) in version 3.6 or use Neo4j 3.